# Multiple Table Inheritance, columns not accessible from sub class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, multi-table-inheritance

UPDATE:
changing table_name to self.table_name = seems to have convinced rails to use the correct table.

I am, however, now getting these weird errors

```
   Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'templates.deleted_at' in 'where clause': SELECT `objekts`.* FROM `objekts`  WHERE (`templates`.`deleted_at` IS NULL)
```

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

I have a Template, and an Objekt:

```
class Template < ActiveRecord::Base
  def status; 0; end # Template doesn't have a status column, so define default
end

class Objekt < Template
  table_name = "objekts" # there is a status column in this table
end
```

but when I do, `Objekt.new.attributes` in the console, it only lists the attributes from the `Template` object, and doesn't list any of the `Objekt`.

Every column on the `Template` is also available in the `Objekt`, but the `Objekt` has an additional 10 columns (mostly flags)

what's going on here? why does rails not hook up the `Objekt` class to the `objekts` table?

Comment: Would a `has_many/belongs_to` relationship not be better here instead of using the Template Method Pattern? Template is more of a `base` class in this case. `Objekt` should be relatable to a table. Convention over configuration.

Comment: Well, Template has a ton of methods that Objekt should also have. that's why I think Inheritance is the best case, here. Mayble Table-Inheritance isn't the right term at all. I want both objects to have entirely separate tables.. it just so happens that the tables share some column names. Mostly, I want to share methods between the two. A module won't work, because then it overrides Objekt's column definitions (or would).

Comment: I prefer to follow the pattern of `composition over inheritance`. Could you not move the methods out of template to a module and include/extend them within Objekt as required? They can then both inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ref the comments above when I refer to composition over inheritance I was thinking about something like this...

```
class Objekt < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Template

  def status
    self.random_column_name || super
  end
end

module Template
  def status
    0
  end
end
```

Comment: It should be noted that this works if status isn't a column name. 
Since, for example, I have random_column_name as a column, I ended up just defining that in my "Super class" and didn't define it in the module.  So, what I learned: Modules can be used for shared methods between two active record models such that those methods are not columns in one of the models.

Comment: Good to hear. Thanks for the tick :)